# Open quickfix Window Only, Don't Jump To First Result

Tags: quickfix, tags

Is there a way to open just the quickfix list without jumping to the first result when using `:lt`? I am using `:lt` to populate the location list with tags that match with the following binding:

```
nmap <expr> <Leader>t ":lt /" . input("", "", "tags") . "<CR>:lop<CR><C-k><C-o><C-j>"
```

which works to some degree. Given that `<C-k>` and `<C-j>` are mappings for the associated window movement commands, this breaks down if the quickfix window is below some complex set of splits. `:h tag-matchlist` and `:h quickfix` don't seem to offer any helpful information. However, some options like `:cgete` seem like the functionality is there, as they specify "but don't jump to the first error", which isn't an option for `:lt` as it specifies"Jump to tag" as part of its behavior.

So, the new question is: *how can I populate the location list with tags matching a pattern without jumping to the first match?*

I am currently working on trying to get it to work with `:taglist()` and `:lgete`.

Comment: While commands like `:make` do jump to the first result (unless suppressed with `!`), I don't see that behavior for `:copen`, nor is it documented. Please check that you don't have some customization (`:autocmd`) that provides this behavior.

Comment: I don't have any `au` setup that would do this. Even with a completely empty `.vimrc`, doing `:lt /<match>` will always jump to the first result. I worded this incorrectly in that this is a behavior of `:lt`, not `:cope/:lop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jump is caused by the `:ltag` command, not by `:lopen`. Unfortunately, though that command takes an optional `[!]`, it's meaning is different than that to `:make` and friends, which can suppress the jump with `!`.

As `:ltag` is just a variant of `:tag`, the `!` there is concerned with abandoning the current file, as [`:help tag-!`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tag-%21) explains.

I guess the right way to solve this issue is through skipping `:ltag` and using low-level functions like [`taglist()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#taglist%28%29) to obtain the tags and [`setloclist()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setloclist%28%29) to populate the location list.

Comment: Doing `nmap <expr> <Leader>z ":call setloclist(0, taglist(\"" . input("", "", "tag") . "\"))<CR>:lop<CR>"` works, so thanks for the tips on this. However, the location list only shows the files. Looking at `:echo taglist("setup_")`, it has a 'name 'field that I think would be useful to show. `:h setqflist` allows custom 'text', but I am having trouble setting it. I've tried using `map()`, but haven't had any luck. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: You don't need to use `<expr>` here; I would first move the implementation into a function, and then, yes, use `map()`, maybe with another inner function.

Comment: Without `<expr>`, I can't pause to wait for user input as far as I understand, right? I've gotten to the point where I'm doing `nmap <expr> <Leader>t ":call setloclist(0, map(taglist(\"" . input("", "", "tags") . "\"), \"extend(v:val, {'text': v:val['name']})\"))<CR>:lop<CR>"`. This works if I get rid of the `input()` call, but when I put it back in it doesn't wait for input before continuing. I will try pulling it out into a function, unless you have further input (no pun intended).